# CSV File to database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created one csv file and need to insert all data in to database.

though data comes in continuos form i have inserted line break in csv file as below.

```
NSString *strCSVFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@\n\r",[discription stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[[dictFavorite valueForKeyPath:@"link.text"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[[dictFavorite valueForKeyPath:@"title.text"]stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];
```

but, now i don't know how to insert this data into database.

Any suggestion is appriceable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file using:

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                             error:NULL];
```

Then separate the file into an array at the line breaks:

```
NSArray *lineArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\r"];
```

Then loop over each object in the `lineArray`:

```
for (NSString *line in lineArray) {
    NSArray *componentArray = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    // At this point the componentArray has the individual objects of each line
    // and you can insert them into the database

    for (NSString *component in componentArray) {
        //insert component into your model.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [CHCSVParser Class](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) by davedelong to parse the CSV file. Then you would iterate the resulting array and save it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

If using raw SQLite3 instead of Core Data is an option, Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial where he populates a database with a simple Python script. The code is provided and can be easily tweaked for your needs.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-creating-and-scripting